# Extracting out parts of a string using c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I needed some guidance on extracting out the Town & Range values from strings that look like the following:

```
ABCD EFG HIJK LMNO, Town 35N, Range 13E
ABCD FFFF HIJK LMNO Town 32N Range 1E
QRS ST LMNO Town 11N, Range 23E HSSS
```

For the first one I'd like to extract out "35N," for Town & "13E" for Range. For the second record it should be "32N" for Town & "1E" for Range and for the last record I should have "11N," for Town & "23E" for Range.

The space after the "35N,", "13E", "32N", "1E", "11N," and "23E" would indicate the end of the value for Town & Range.

I'm not really familiar with regex, so some good resources on that would be helpful as well.

Comment: What Regex have you tried?

Comment: Is there a defined pattern for the town and range values you want to extract (eg. "one or two digits followed by a capital letter")?

Comment: Check this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/coPU7Z).

Comment: The space after the 35N, 13E, 32N, 1E, 11N, and 23E would indicate that the range & township has ended

Comment: So `35N,` is the first value then, *including* the comma? Since you say that the space character is what delimits the town from the range?

Comment: Yes @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: So what is **the exact** result you want? Do you want one string containing `"Town 35N,"` and another string containing `"Range 13E"`? Or do you want 1 string containing `"Town 35N, Range 13E"`, or do you want two strings with just `"35N,"` and `"13E"`?

Comment: I've corrected the question @LasseV.Karlsen. Thank you for pointing that out. I would like 2 strings "35N," & "13E"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do the trick :

```
Town ([0-9]{1,2}[\D])|Range ([0-9]{1,2}[\D])
```

https://regex101.com/r/lH3pJ0/1